# WP plugin image upload

Tags: php, wordpress, image, mysqli

```
$pid = $wpdb->insert_id; 
$newname = "$pid.jpg";

$dir = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($dir);
    echo "</pre><br>";  
move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "images/$newname");


$message ="directoryBase inserted";
```

The above is my attempt at debugging this Wordpress snippet. Basically I'm creating a mini directory of people.

Right above this snippet of code is my MYSQLI insert statement which upon execution returns my $pid.
The `ID` is inserted into the database then I use that to match and pull url when I'm ready to display the image as the row is called from the database.

Typically I create a directory for images then set them to this directory as done above. The folder images/ is located within the plugin main directory.

The issue I'm having is determining the `move_uploaded_file` line.

Is there a specific way I can figure out how far up or down to move to find the correct directory. I can't  throw any errors and no image is added to my custom plugin directory as intended.

I'm not completely up to snuff with Wordpress, but I do know enough PHP to be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Before moving the files into any directory Keep following steps in mind:

1. Check what kind of file you want to upload, like images, pdf, word files etc.
2. Check the size of files if its neccessary to you.
3. Check the directory where you want to upload files is exists or not, Make sure you have increased 
   uploaded max size from `php.ini` file
4. Check the permission of the directory

If all the above points passed then proceed with `move_uploaded_file()`.
Now with your script check if the images directory exists in your plugin or wherever you want to store.

```
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path
$path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__);
if( ! is_dir($path.'images') ) {
    mkdir($path.'images', 0755);
}
```

Then Use `move_uploaded_file` like this

```
// Return true if file moved successfully
if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], $path."images/$newname") ) {
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This should work but you should never ever set 0777 permissions on directories or files as it is not secure. If you use mkdir, use 0755 permissions for directories.